# Is なきにしもあらず~なきに a set phrase?

Tags: grammar, set-phrases, word-usage

This sentence recently appeared in one of my N1 training books:

> 彼女が合格する可能性は**なきにしもあらず**だが、彼がパスする可能性は**なき**にひとしい。
>
> My translation: While she may have a slight chance of passing the exam, it is hopeless for him. (lit. his chances are the same as nothing)

Is [なきにしもあらず~なきに] a set phrase that often/always comes as a pair? Or can I use 「なきにしもあらず」 also without the following contrasting 「なきに」 and still sound natural?

Comment: https://biz.trans-suite.jp/15107

Answer (score 3, accepted):

無きにしもあらず ("not zero", "cannot say never") and [無きに等しい](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E7%84%A1%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AB%E7%AD%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%84) ("virtually zero", "nearly no") are two different set phrases which are not directly related to each other. You can safely use one of them without using the other.